# Is there a .NET collection interface that prevents adding objects?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, list

I have a class that maintains list of objects of another class. List of objects is a public property. I would like to prevent users from adding and removing objects directly to list like this:

```
      MyObject.MyListProperty.Add(object);
```

Instead I want them to use method that will internally do some processing and then add object to list.

I have some ideas:

- create descendant of `List<T>` and override add and remove
- return fresh copy of list through property getter (list is relatively short, not more than 30 objects)

Is there some collection interface that does not have Add and Remove?

**Edit:**
I'm going to go with `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Reason is that wrapped collection can be updated and changes will be immediately visible in read only object (see MSDN code examples for [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) and [`AsReadOnly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx)). This allows that read only list be created only once.

The problem with `IEnumerable` is that object can be casted back to original `List<T>` and then 
directly manipulated.

Comment: I was also looking for this
+1

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) - wrap your collection in this and return the `ReadOnlyCollection` to users of your class:

```
return new ReadOnlyCollection(innerCollection);
```

Or using the `AsReadOnly` method of the `List<T>` class:

```
return innerCollection.AsReadOnly();
```

The [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface will do what you need, as it only has one member `GetEnumerator()`, that will only let you iterate over items.

Comment: `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `AsReadOnly` only accepts `IList<T>`. Is there a solution for `ICollection<T>` as well?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [AsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) method will do the trick, to hand a read-only instance to public.

Otherwise, `IEnumerable<T>` has no `Add` nor `Remove`, so you can do something like:

```
private List<int> _myList;
public IEnumerable<int> MyList
{
   get
   {
      return this._myList.ToList();
   }
}
```

I would rather go for the `IEnumerable<T>` (+ copy) as for `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, because: changes to your base list (which your read-only collection is created from) will immediately show up in your instance of the read-only collection. this may cause locking and straaange problems :)

Comment: why `return this._myList.ToList();` and not `return this._myList;`

Comment: What about `IList<int>` and `ToArray`? Best of both worlds, no?

Comment: IList has an Add method, so the list wouldn't be readonly, and you can change the contents of an array (not that that would affect this class since the array is a copy). The only interface that solves the OP's problem is IEnumerable

Comment: i'm not that fan of arrays... dunno why ... if you hack my example a bit more, you can have a true iterator-pass-through implementation , which is much more better than creating another object (array) to iterate through elements!

Comment: @Rob Fonseca-Ensor: simple: hand out a copy, not the same ref. the caller my cast it to a list and can modified your internal datastore!

Answer (score 5):

Your easiest option would be to expose your list as one of the following [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx), [ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection_members.aspx) [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) via a public property.

So you could create your own `type` of list which exposes your `Items` as one of the above but has an internal method for the adding e.g.

```
public class MyList<MyType>
{
    private List<MyType> items;

    public MyList()
    {
        items = new List<MyType>();
    }

    public IEnumerable Items { get { return items.AsEnumerable(); } }
    public Add(MyType item)
    {
        // do internal processing
        items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't prevent casting the collection back to List<MyType> and calling Add on it. ReadOnlyCollection is the way to go if you really need to prevent Adds. Also, there's no need to call items.AsEnumerable and I don't think this will compile as written because AsEnumerable() will return IEnumerable<MyType> and Items is typed as IEnumerable.

Comment: @Jamie `IEnumerable<MyType>` inherits from `IEnumerable`, so it will compile, but I agree that they should return IEnumerable<MyType>, and that AsEnumerable is redundant.

Comment: @Jamie, it will compile, however, I do agree the cast is possible. This was just an example to show what the user can do as I have mentioned previously in the post that ReadOnlyCollection *is* an option. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, only `IEnumerable<T>` will provide this without exposing any `Add` and `Remove` public methods that might trick the client into getting a runtime exception.

If you want your public API to explicitely state that the collection is read-only and you need an indexer, you will have to write your own wrapper around existing `List<T>` or `T[]`.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't support random access though

Answer (score 0):

You could just give them an object which always returns an enumerator that they can use to access the structure?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really answer your question, but is useful information if you decide to implement one of your two ideas:
You can use ToArray to create a copy and return an array.

Or you can do something like this:
http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Generics_Recipes%E2%80%94Making_Read-Only_Collections_the_Generic_Way

Answer (score 0):

ICollection (the non-generic version) only got IEnumerable + Count