# Generic list of lists, converting List<List<T>> to IList<IList<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ienumerable, ilist

We're using a class library that performs calculations on 3D measurement data, it exposes a method:

```
MeasurementResults Calculate(IList<IList<Measurement>> data)
```

I would like to allow calling this method with any indexable list of lists (of Measurement of course), for example both:

```
Measurement[][] array;
List<List<Measurement>> list;
```

Calling the method using the array works fine, which is a bit strange. Is there some compiler trick at work here? Trying to call with the `List` gives the familiar error:

```
cannot convert from 'List<List<Measurement>>' to 'IList<IList<Measurement>>'
```

So, I have written a facade class (containing some other things as well), with a method that splits the generic definition between the argument and method and converts to the IList type if necessary:

```
MeasurementResults Calculate<T>(IList<T> data) where T : IList<Measurement>
{
  IList<IList<Measurement>> converted = data as IList<IList<Measurement>>;
  if(converted == null)
    converted = data.Select(o => o as IList<Measurement>).ToList();
  return Calculate(converted);
}
```

Is this a good way to solve the problem, or do you have a better idea?

Also, while testing different solutions to the problem, I found out that if the class library method had been declared with `IEnumerable` instead of `IList`, it is ok to call the method using both the array and the `List`:

```
MeasurementResults Calculate(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Measurement>> data)
```

I suspect that there is some compiler trick at work again, I wonder why they haven't made `IList` work with `List` while they were at it?

Comment: Calling the `IList<IList<T>>` method with a `T[][]` works because of broken array covariance.  It is broken because the compiler would allow you to assign a `List<T>` to an element of the `IList<IList<T>>`, but if the object is really a `T[][]`, the assignment will fail at run time.

Comment: @phoog: Aha, interesting, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a method

```
void Bar(IList<IList<int>> foo)
```

Within `Bar`, it should then be perfectly admissible to add a `int[]` to `foo` - after all, `int[]` implements `IList<int>`, doesn't it?

But if we had called `Bar` with a `List<List<int>>`, we would now be trying to add a `int[]` to something that only accepts a `List<int>`! which would be *bad*. So the compiler doesn't let you do this.

> Also, while testing different solutions to the problem, I found out that if the class library method had been declared with `IEnumerable` instead of `IList`, it is ok to call the method using both the array and the `List`:

Indeed, because if the behavioural contract just says "I can **output** `int`s", nothing can go wrong. The key terms for further research are *covariance* and *contravariance*, and no one<sup>*</sup> can ever remember which is which.

In your particular case, if `Calculate` is only ever *reading* its input, changing it to consume `IEnumerable` is absolutely the right thing to do - it both allows you to pass in any qualifying objects, and it further **communicates** to anyone reading the signature that this method is intentionally designed to only **consume**, not mutate, its input.

---

*<sup>*</sup> well, mostly no one*

Comment: An easy way to remember covariance versus contravariance is to think about what happens when things nest.  If `Foo<T>` is *co*variant, the relationship between `Foo<T>` and `Foo<U>` will be the same as the relationship between `T` and `U`.  If `Foo<T>` is *contra*variant, the relationship will be opposite.  Interestingly, if `Foo<T>` is either covariant or contravariant with respect to `T`, `Foo<Foo<T>>` will be covariant (a routine which is covariant with respect to `T` is generally one that supplies `T`'s; a routine which accepts consumers of type `T` is expected to supply `T`'s to them).

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Calculate do only read the data, but I'm hesitant to changing it to IEnumerable since we need random access using the indexing property. We could do a `.ToList()` inside Calculate, but that would cause all the data to be copied to new lists which might cause performance problem instead. It seems like no readonly indexable collection interface exists?

Comment: @Anlo now that's a good question! but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141748/indexable-interface) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176246/is-there-a-net-collection-interface-that-prevents-adding-objects) suggest the answer is no. By all means create your own `IReadOnlyList<>`, though.

Answer (score 6):

It's okay to do this with `IEnumerable<T>`, because that is *covariant in `T`*. It wouldn't be safe to do that with `IList<T>`, as that is used for both "input" and "output".

In particular, consider:

```
List<List<Foo>> foo = new List<List<Foo>>();
List<IList<Foo>> bar = foo;
bar.Add(new Foo[5]); // Arrays implement IList<T>

// Eh?
List<Foo> firstList = foo[0];
```

See MSDN for more information about [generic covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Comment: And of course, declaring the method with `IList<IList<T>>` and calling it with `T[][]` works because of broken array covariance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things with you implementation that I would change. First of all it might insert nulls into the result where there were objects in the original. Personally I would prefer it to throw.

```
MeasurementResults Calculate<T>(IList<T> data) where T : IList<Measurement>
{
    return Calculate(data as IList<IList<Measurement>>
                     ?? data.Cast<IList<Measurement>>().ToList());
}
```

Is a short example a like what I would personally do in your case, though I doubt I would actually implement the method. The interface was written like that for a reason (I hope) and I would try to use that knowledge in my implementation on top instead of fighting it if possible. Any changes made to the list in the method will not be reflected in the original list if you use your code (or anything like that). It's a new list being passed to the method and since the signature asks for an IList it's possible that changes can be made.

Aside from not potentially having nulls in the list instead of objects I've change to use the cast method since that's basically what you are trying to accomplish. (Cast does not allow for custom conversion operators).

Comment: Yes, throwing exceptions instead of silently exchanging objects for null values is definately a good idea. But are you sure my code can introduce null values in the list? The `where T : IList<Measurement>` should prohibit anything not castable to `IList<Measurement>`, or have I missed something? Also, I haven't really thought about the fact that a new list is passed down to Calculate. In this case that was not a problem, since the data is only read by the method - but it sure could matter in the general case.

Comment: Also, the Cast is a lot cleaner and more informational than my Select.

Comment: @anlo I must admit I forgot about the constraint and only read the code but then I guess that's a good example of why information scattering leads to misunderstanding (a completely different topic but very related to an area of work for me called DCI) so thks for a nice example there :)