# How to override or hide add in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to override `Add(MyType t)` for a class derived from `ObservableCollection<MyType>`. However I cannot override Add. Why?

I therefore added `AddIem(MyType t)`and use that function instead, which works fine. But I want to prevent someone erroneously using `Add` so I implemented Add (throwing an exception). But that doesn't hide the Add method of the ObservableCollection. Any idea why and how I could achieve my goal?

Comment: Possible duplicate [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2176263/579895)

Comment: a 5 seconds google search led me to the following answer: 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/555226-Is-it-possible-to-override-ObservableCollectionTAdd

Comment: Related read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your ObservableCollection private, and expose the items with a public [ReadOnlyObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which reflects the items in the private collection.

If you need to expose a specialized AddItem method to other classes, you could make it a member of your viewmodel class, or you could subclass ReadOnlyObservableCollection and put it there. Call it MostlyReadOnlyObservableCollection.

Comment: Thanks, Ed, I'll make it a private member.